# How resize/drag/drop image over a youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube

I am working on a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpeehsxn/32/embedded/result) in which I want to resize/drag/drop an image over a youtube video.

In the above fiddle, I cannot resize the **image at fast pace** over the youtube video. I am not sure what are the reasons behind it. I can resize/drop/drag but **not at a very fast pace.**

The HTML/JS I have used in order to achieve the above fiddle is:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<div id="wrapper" style="display:inline-block">
    <img id="image" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</div>
```

**JS(JQuery):**

```
$(function() {
$('#wrapper').draggable();
$('#image').resizable();
});
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the HTML code so that I am able to resize the `Google Image` properly. At this moment, it seems like I am not able to resize the **image at fast pace**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

youtube video complicates it, so create an overlay over video and make it visible when resize event starts, and hide when resize stops.

```
$('#image').resizable({
start: function( event, ui ) {
 $('#overlay').show();
},

stop: function( event, ui ) {
 $('#overlay').hide();
 }
 }
);
});
```

working code: https://jsfiddle.net/obn4yph0/

Comment: @ErcanPerker Hey, what you did. This is what I want. Amazing.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. Now, I have one more similar question which is the main reason why I am working on this. In your fiddle, let  suppose I place the `google image over the nose of a guy` and if I resize the browser window, the `google image doesn't seem to stay over the nose`. Did you get my question ?

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: you can store x,y coordinates and width of image relative to video width and height  when resize and drag stops. then on window resize you can calculate new width and coordinates relative to new video size.

Comment: Can you give me more pointer how can we implement that in the code ?

Comment: Are you around ? I am wondering if you can give me a demo in fiddle.

Comment: @EcranPeker I have one quick question. Parent div class of overlay doesn't seem to have closing tag. I am asking your opinion where the closing tag of div should be. Let me know your thoughts because `<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">` or `<div class="overlay" id="overlay" />` (either one of them) doesn't have a closing div tag.